# Difference between score and explained score

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I get invalid search results every time with elasticsearch. I ran a query with `explain: true` and checked results. I was surprised that 'messy' output entries has different `score` and `explained score`:

`"_score": 0.32287252,
...
"_explanation": {
          "value": 1.6143626,
          "description": "product of:",
...`

If those (messy) entries had explained score's value in `_score`, output would look perfect. Does anybody know how to fix this?

PS: I tried to change the number of shards from 5 to 1: nothing changes, the output is still invalid.

Comment: Which ES version? And what's the complete output of `explain` for a wrongly calculated score?

Comment: @AndreiStefan 2.3.3, here is the full explanation: http://pastebin.com/NDSk1rDk  _score is 0.32287252, explain value: 1.6143626